# Poyla URN - computing the probability to pick a black ball at the nth turn

Tags: probability, markov-process

Consider the Polya  urn model with $a$ black balls and $b$ red balls initially in an urn where $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary positive integers. At each turn you pick a ball at random and return it to the urn along with a ball with the same color. Let $X_n$ denote the number of black balls in the urn after the $n$th turn is completed.

I need to compute $P_b = $ {probability that the $n$th pick is black} and prove that
$P_b  = \frac{a}{a+b}$ for every n

I was able to prove that $$ E \left( \frac{X_n}{n+a+b} \mid X_{n-1} \right)= \frac{X_{n-1}}{n+a+b-1}.
$$

And also computed  $ E\left( \frac{X_n}{n+a+b}  \right)= \frac{a}{a+b}$
But I'm still stuck on proving that $P_b  = \frac{a}{a+b}$ for every n

edit : Is it ok to write  $P_b  = \frac{X_{n-1}}{n+a+b-1}$ which is the number of black balls after $n-1$ turns divided by the total number of balls after $n-1$ turns and now take the expected value from both sides and have   $$E(P_b)  = E( \frac{X_{n-1}}{n+a+b-1}) = E(X_{n-1}) \frac{1}{n+a+b-1} = \frac{ a(n+a+b-1) }{a+b} \frac{1} {(n+a+b-1) } =  \frac{a}{a+b} \\$$
and since $P_b $ is a constant $E(P_b)= P_b$ and I got what I wanted ?

Answer (score 1):

The expectation that you have computed is the expected number of black balls at time $n$, divided by the total number of balls at time $n$.

How would you define the probability of drawing a black ball?

Comment: The probability of drawing a black ball is the number black balls at turn n  divided by the total number of balls at turn n.

Comment: Exactly - this is what you have already calculated.

Comment: How do you show that $P_b$ is actually the same as  the expected value ? I edited my question with a thought on how to show that.

Comment: First, consider that what we know is actually a conditional probability: $P(\text{\{nth pick is black\}}\mid X_{n-1})$, since we know the probability *given* $X_{n-1}$. From here on you can simply calculate $P(\text{\{nth pick is black\}})= \sum_k P(\text{\{nth pick is black\}}\mid X_{n-1}=k)P(X_{n-1}=k)$ by the law of total probability and identify the definition of the expectation of $E[X_{n-1}]$ in the resulting expression. Or you can calculate $P(\text{\{nth pick is black\}}) = E[P(\text{\{nth pick is black\}}\mid X_{n-1})]$ by the tower property of conditional expectation.